# cursor left click and hold from batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

hello I am trying to have a cursor left click and hold from a batch file. I am using the command `nircmd movecursor X Y` to move the cursor I just need a way for my mouse to left click and hold it. an example would be to move a window in windows using this script

```
@echo off
nircmd.exe setcursor X Y ::move the cursor into position
left click and hold
nircmd.exe movecursor X Y ::move the window into position
```

what I am trying to do specifically needs a setup like this. I can use other languages if that would be easier. Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/) or [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com/)...

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36095443/388389)

Comment: @npocmaka if you answer this I will mark it as correct. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with [mouse.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/mouse.bat).I think the drag switch is what you need:

```
//relative drag (lefclick and move)
call mouse dragBy 300x200

//absolute drag
call mouse dragTo 500x500
```

More examples can be [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095443/388389).