# Mouse clicking script for Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to programming and I started with Batch. I learned some basics, like to make an RPG game etc... But I need a "clicking" script or anything that will alow me to click a text such as "echo Play" so when I click "Play" with mouse it should proceed to the next code. I think this is possible to make but I don't know I am just beginner.

Here is example for this:

```
@echo off
title RPG
cls

:start
cls
echo Play
echo Exit
echo.
set /p=Click
if %click% == play goto :play
if %click% == exit exit

:play
cls
echo Welcome to the game!
echo.
pause
```

So I know how this `set /p` and `if %%` works, but this was just example on how it by how I think should work. I would be thankful if someone could write a code so I could just paste it. Thank you!

Comment: Batch can't natively interact with the mouse. Use VBScript or PowerShell.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36095443/388389)

Comment: Uh bro, as I said I am begginer in programming so I don't know how your code works. I pasted it to my Notepad++ and saved (only the Batch code pasted) and opened it one time to see if something will happen but I don't understand it. Can you explain it with a simple code like if you click on an text such as "echo Start" (to click on Start) it will proceed to the next command?

Comment: The code to do what you want is not even remotely simple.

Comment: @miragetv7 SomethingDark's solution is already simple enough. *You could try VBS or even the batbox.exe, but that's 1000 times more complicated than just some call statements.*