# Execute options in "File" Context Menu with batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible with a batch file to open a file then execute or "click" an option in the opened application "File" menu with just one `.bat` file?

So for example normally I would double-click the Firefox shortcut on my desktop then click on "File" > "New Tab".

Is it possible to do that with a single `.bat` file?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807543/windows-command-script-that-moves-mouse-cursor-n-pixels/53769159

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CursorPos.exe` by @Aacini to move the cursor. Here is the download link: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3428. In the download page, you can only download the set of .exe files. Extract `CursorPos.exe`  from them.

> Usage: 
>   CursorPos [[±]col [±]row]
>   If no parameter is given, return current cursor position as col+(row<<16) in ERRORLEVEL.
>   If any coordinate have sign, the position given is relative to the current one.
>   If cursor is moved, the Ascii code of the character at new position is returned in ERRORLEVEL.

And for mouse input you can use `batbox.exe`. Download link: https://batchprogrammers.blogspot.com/2016/06/batbox-awesome-batch-plugin-by.html?m=1. The full information is available there.

Comment: I've done some more research and found out about ".SendKeys". Would it be easier to maybe to use ".SendKeys" somehow to do "Alt+F" to open the File Context Menu then "Down Arrow" to select an option then "Enter" to execute it?

Comment: No it will be much harder than you think. You will need more complex scripts and the error chance will be more. So I suggest you to use these tools to make menu.

Comment: I'm very new to batch files and batch commands. Can you maybe post an simple example of using CursorPos.exe and batbox.exe? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: My browser is saying: "We can’t connect to the server at www.dos9.org". I am unable to download batbox.exe :(

Comment: Sorry for the unavailable link. I am giving a new link in its place.